# Subset Dataframe by Filtered Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I'm wondering what the most efficient way to update a dataframe I'm working with is.
The 'location' column has some locations that I'd like to filter out.  I'd like to keep locations only with more than two items (> than two rows).
[image: head and tail of df][image: snapshot of unique locations]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a little convoluted, but it should get the job done.

Get a list of all the locations with more than 2 occurrences:

```
counts = df['location'].value_counts()
filt = counts[counts > 2]
```

Filter the original data to pull out only the locations (`keys()`) that occur >2 times

```
filt2 = df['location'].isin(filt.keys())
```

Apply the filter

```
print(df[filt2])
```